# How to write QueryBuilder Query to clean set or list value in Cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra

Given a table:

```
CREATE TABLE User (
  id text,
  emails set<text>,
  PRIMARY KEY ((id))
)
```

How do I write the equivalent of the query below using QueryBuilder?

```
UPDATE User  SET emails = {} where id='xxx'
```

By checking QueryBuilder class I found how to add/remove specific elements, and how to set a non-list, but not how to clear the list without specifying every element.

Answer (score 0):

Setting to null apparently have the exact same result, so:

```
QueryBuilder.update("User")
 .where(QueryBuilder.eq("id","xxx"))
 .with(QueryBuilder.set("emails",null))
```

Did the trick.